# Positive dot products and special linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

I would be very happy if there would be a short proof of the following fact:

> Let $w, w_1, \dots, w_k$ be vectors in ${\mathbb{R}}^n$ with rational
>   entries. Suppose that for every $v \in {\mathbb{R}}^n$ such that $w \cdot v > 0,$ we have $w_i \cdot v > 0$ for some $i.$ Then $w = {c_1}{w_1} + \dots + {c_k}{w_k}$ for some nonnegative rational numbers
>   $c_1, \dots, c_k.$

I have quite a long proof so I would appreciate even a reference, thanks

Comment: Google Farkas lemma.

Comment: can you give a reference for this form of Farkas please?

Comment: From Farkas lemma follows the existence of $c_i\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Moreover, if $w_1,\ldots, w_k$ are l.i. then it is possible to obtain $c_i\in\mathbb{Q}^+$. I am not sure otherwise.

Comment: @Daniel, if a rational vector is a real linear combination of some rational vectors, then it is also a rational linear combination of those rational vectors --- you're just solving a system of linear equations with rational coefficients, which you can do by "rational operations". It's obvious [meaning: I don't see exactly how to prove it right at this moment] that if there's a real solution then there are rational solutions arbitrarily nearby.

Comment: any updates on this? I wasn't able to prove it using Farkas